# Can't parse JSON from req.body

Tags: json, ajax, node.js, express

Using node express, can't I parse the req.body after an ajax post. The body comes through but seems to be wrapped in an additional object which prevents parsing.

*profileController.client.js*

```
 function submitNewPoll(){
    var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('.fc-newpoll-option')
    var polltitle = document.querySelector('.fc-newpoll-title').value
    var payload = {
        polltitle: polltitle
    }
    inputs.forEach(function(input, index) {
        if (!input.value || input.value == '')  {abort = true}
            payload["option" + (index + 1)] = input.value
   })

   ajaxFunctions.ajax({
       method: 'POST',
       url: '/newpoll',
       success: function(){console.log('success')},
       error: function(err){console.log('error', err)},
       payload: JSON.stringify(payload)
    })
}
```

at this point the logged stringifed payload looks correct:

```
{"polltitle":"tree","option1":"oak","option2":"willow"}
```

*ajaxFunctions.ajax*

```
ajax: function ajaxByObj (req) {
  const url = req.url;
  const method = req.method || 'get';
  const successCallback = req.success;
  const errorCallback = req.error;
  const contentType = req.contentType || "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
  const dataType = req.dataType || 'json';
  const payload = req.payload || ''; 
  console.log(payload)
  let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open(method, url)
  xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", contentType)
  xhr.responseType = dataType
  xhr.onload = function () {
     let _this = this
     if (this.status == 200) {
        successCallback(_this.response)
     } else {
        errorCallback(_this.response)
     }
  }
  xhr.send(payload)
}
```

*and in the request handler for the router in express*

```
this.addNewPoll = function(req, res) {
   console.log('raw', req.body)
   var polldata = JSON.parse(req.body)
   console.log('parsed:', polldata)
   var title = polldata.polltitle
   console.log('title',title)
   var fields = []
   for (var prop in polldata) {
      if (prop != 'poll title') {            
        fields.push({"name": polldata[prop], "votes": 0})
      }
   }
```

the logged *raw* req.body data looks like this

```
raw { '{"polltitle":"tree","option1":"oak","option2":"willow"}': '' }
```

you can see the data is wrapped in another object with an empty string value

when i attempt to JSON.parse this data it throws an exception

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token o
```

please help me to find out what I am doing wrong

thanks!

Comment: You're setting the content type to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, even though it's JSON.

Comment: Thank you so much. Sometimes it is the little things that cause the biggest headaches